# Assigning a "rank" to a arrayList's items stored inside a HashMap

Tags: java, algorithm, arraylist, hashmap

first time asking a question here and I hope somebody can help me.

I've been banging my head over this for a couple of hours, and I can't seem to find anything that works.

I have a `HashMap` whose keys are numbers, representing the frequency of a word, and values are `ArrayLists` storing said words. I want to assign a "rank" to each word, but i cant find a way to give each of them a different ranking. For example, lets say i have the words "Hello" and "Bye", each with a frequency of 4. I store them inside a `HashMap` as such: `{4 = ["Hello", "Bye"]}` and I want to rank them based on their frequency. My current algorithm assigns them the same rank but I don't want that... I'm storing that rank and word inside a new `HashMap<String, Integer>`, since I need to look these up later.

Is there a simple way to do this? If so, how?

Desired output:

```
{"Bye" = 1, "Hello = 2} or {"Hello" = 1, "Bye" = 2} not {"Hello" = 1, "Bye" = 1}
```

<s>EDIT: Okay, as I was writing this, the solution came to me. I checked if the "rank" I'm putting in is already a value in my new `HashMap`, and if it is, then I added 1 to the rank in order to make it +1 bigger than the previous.</s>

Comment: It is really hard to understand what exactly be a "good fit" to you, but a simple solution is to tie break two words with the same frequency by [lexicographic order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) of them

Comment: Your solution would fail for `{1=["Hello", "Bye"], 2=["Ouch"]}`

Comment: Don't see how your solution would work. What if you have a word with a frequency of 2, then you had two words with a frequency of 1? The first word would rank 2, the second 1, and the third 3. But that's completely off! Though it's very hard to provide useful input without actual code to reference.

Answer (score 1):

Write a class having fields for both word and rank. Then store that class objects in arraylist in hashmap rather than simple strings.

Answer (score 1):

It is really hard to understand what exactly be a "good fit" to you, but a simple solution is to tie break two words with the same frequency by [lexicographic order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) of them, so if you have some words with the same frequency, give a "bonus" to the words which are "higher"  in lexigoraphic order (or lower, doesn't really matters, just be consistent).

Getting the score for all words in your map will be easier if you use a `TreeMap` instead of a `HashMap`, and iterate to assign values.

java like Pseudo code:

```
val = 1
for (Entry<Integer,ArrayList<String>> e : myMap.EntrySet()) { 
  ArrayList<String> arrList = e.getValue();
  Collections.sort(arrList);
  for (String s : arrList) {
     //yield s with the value 'val'
     val++;  
  }
}
```

EDIT:

Your solution would fail for `{1=["Hello", "Bye"], 2=["Ouch"]}`, you will give both "Bye" and "Ouch" the same 'rank'.